# Sftp cannot see folder in destination server

Tags: ftp, file-permissions, sftp

I'm using sftp to connect from a Windows server (User ID is ssh1) to AIX server (User ID is ftpeapsg) to access /sftp/ftphrssg/HRSSG/EAPSG in AIX server. 
User ftpeapsg is created on AIX server.
Able to connect to AIX server fine without the need for password however not able to see the folder /sftp/ftphrssg/HRSSG/EAPSG

For /sftp/ftphrssg/HRSSG/EAPSG, owner is ftphrssg and group is geapsgtp
ftp user is ftpeapsg and group is geapsgtp

Both /sftp/ftphrssg/HRSSG/EAPSG and ftpeapsg belong to group geapsgtp.
Any idea why I'm not able to see /sftp/ftphrssg/HRSSG/EAPSG in the AIX server?

Comment: What is the actual error message? What client-program are you using on Windows (Putty!psftp would be a good choice.)

Comment: Also use command `ls -ld` on every (sub)directory in question to find out their access rights.